# Understanding virtual to physical memory translation in Android (google pixel 5, armv8.2-a)

Tags: adb, ram

I am using a simple shell script to read out data from `/proc/pid/mem`.

**Setup:** This is done through android studio by using `adb shell` and `su`.
Then, I use `/proc/pid/maps` to read out a memory range, starting with the beginning of the mmap region. Finally, I run print_pagemap.sh with arguments for pid, start and end address. The memory is populated using mmap and a random char generator.

```
    void* ptr = mmap(NULL, mmapSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_POPULATE, -1, 0);

    if (ptr == NULL) {
        // Memory allocation failed, ptr is not a valid virtual address
        LOGI("malloc failed");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        // Memory allocation successful, ptr is a valid virtual address
        LOGI("Virtual address: %p", ptr);
    }
    // Fill all of mmap with random chars
    for (size_t i = 0; i < mmapSize; ++i) {
        ((char*)ptr)[i] = 'A' + rand() % 95 + 32; // Generate printable ASCII characters
    }
```

**The Question:** I get the output of various memory sections in hexadecimal format, but it does not seem to comply with what would be expected when looking at [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt). Some entries do not have the 63rd bit set to 1 and the bits 60-57 to zero. How is this possible?
I've read up that little endian representation is the standard for this setup.

```
redfin:/data/local/tmp # ./print_pagemap.sh 24708 0x7c437ae000 0x7c437ae100                                                                                                                                                        
00000000: a69cb9b4aa6b8270 76918d87b271ad80 8889706d8f7b6762 6f8f8b899a676380  .....k.pv....q....pm.{gbo....gc.
00000020: 9fbb728a63939679 61639cb070867097 ae7fa47b96a77ca2 76a36bafa66e6d86  ..r.c..yac..p.p....{..|.v.k..nm.
00000040: 667bac66ad827eaa 81b69a907da66768 62a77f958e9b77a1 7b7e9062889c848b  f{.f..~.....}.ghb.....w.{~.b....
00000060: b67090a091aa88b1 a0be7eb9a581bea3 697d7893b48e746d a9a16b717a8e9b6e  .p........~.....i}x...tm..kqz..n
00000080: 9d68ad6bb175b88f 717685b593809898 9dad6c8e7b7c9a61 b9a172746fa981a8  .h.k.u..qv........l.{|.a..rto...
000000a0: ae6bb29c7da76b8d b98d7f8da9b66583 a36db1bb8688b87f 6a679278b0af619e  .k..}.k.......e..m......jg.x..a.
000000c0: baaf7a749482a08d abbeb694b1bbb792 68a58a8d6d82a976 897b8b766888b062  ..zt............h...m..v.{.vh..b
000000e0: 746a75a788b17270 af68a19d63986f68 7d959186b77a9c7d 926792998e82979e  tju...rp.h..c.oh}....z.}.g......
```

Edit: print_pagemap.sh

```
#!/system/bin/sh

# Make sure three arguments are provided
if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <pid> <start_address> <end_address>"
    exit 1
fi

# Extract arguments
pid="$1"
start_address="$2"
end_address="$3"

# Convert hexadecimal addresses to decimal
start_address_dec=$(printf "%d" $start_address)
end_address_dec=$(printf "%d" $end_address)

# Use dd to read data between the addresses
dd if="/proc/$pid/mem" bs=1 skip=$start_address_dec count=$(($end_address_dec - $start_address_dec)) status=none | xxd -g 8 -c 32 | grep -v '0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000'
```

Comment: You should better post the code of `print_pagemap.sh` so we can understand what you are talking about. Because at the moment I only read "the 63rd bit" of <undefined>.

Comment: I've added the suggested code.